# Is there a lodash or other function to search an array of object arrays for a matching key/value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of objects. 
For each object, there's one key I need to use to search in an set of arrays of similar objects to see if they have a value for one key in my object, and if all those similar arrays have the SAME value, I want to set it as the value for the object wit

Is there a better way to find if all the searchable arrays. There's gotta be some awesome, elegant lodash function...right?

```
myValues[] = [{'id': 7, 'score': null}, {'id': 3, 'score': null}];
const searchme[] = /* data fetch*/; 
// sample searchme[] =[
//  [{'id': 1, 'score': 1}, {'id': 2, 'score': 1}, {'id': 3, 'score': 1}],
//  [{'id': 1, 'score': 2}, {'id': 2, 'score': 1}, {'id': 4, 'score': 3}],
//  [{'id': 1, 'score': 1}, {'id': 2, 'score': 1}, {'id': 3, 'score': 1}],
// ];
// searchme[] contains 1-5 arrays like myValues[];
// so searchme[0] = [{'id': 2, 'score': 2}, {'id': 7, 'score': 2}], and so on
// theoretically, each searchme[] array has all the ids all the others do 
// - but a few might be missing

myValues.forEach(v => {

  let score: number = null;
  let started: boolean = false;
  let fail: boolean = false;

  searchme.forEach( anArray => {
    found = anArray.find( search => search.id = v.id);
    if (found) { 
      if (!started) { started = true; score = found.score; }
      else { if (score != found.score) { fail = true; }
    } else { 
      fail = true; 
    }
  });

  if (!fail) { v.score = score; }

});
```

This does work, but it seems super inefficient. Whaddaya think? Got some lodash chops to slap me with? :)

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to flatten the searchme array, index it by ids.

(groupBy produces an object, keyed by the property name whose values are arrays of original objects with that key).

Not sure how to handle instances with the same id and different scores. For this, uniq() forces uniqueness on a given property.

```js
let searchme = [
  [{
    'id': 1,
    'score': 1
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'score': 1
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'score': 1
  }],
  [{
    'id': 1,
    'score': 2
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'score': 1
  }, {
    'id': 4,
    'score': 3
  }],
  [{
    'id': 1,
    'score': 1
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'score': 1
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'score': 1
  }],
];

let grouped = _.groupBy(_.flatten(searchme), 'id')
// now grouped is:
// { 1: [ {...} ],           // the one object with id==1
//   2: [ {...}, {...} ],    // the two objects with id==2
//   etc

function scoresForId(id) {
  let matches = grouped[id]
  return _.uniq(matches, 'score')
}

console.log(scoresForId(2))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: searchme[] is an array of arrays of objects; would I need to make searchMeKeyed an array of _.keyBy(), and then search each of them, or will _.keyBy aggregate arrays of objects?

Comment: @Pól - ah, missed that in the comments.  You might me looking for flatten.  See edit

Comment: Hmm. So, I need to see if the value for that id in *every* array is the same, and THEN set it. So I think if I made an array of keyed search arrays that might shorten it, but it still isn't comparing multiple arrays...

Comment: @Pól - I must be suffering from less understanding of the question than I thought I had. Can you add a little more pseudo data (i.e. are ids unique across the sub-arrays? are they unique within the sub arrays? can objects with the same id have different scores? Whatever that turns out to be, I'm likely to recommend a form of this answer:  preprocess the data to make the lookup quicker.

Comment: searchme[] arrays all conntain the same kind of objects as each other and myValues.
What I think the first step is is to compare all the arrays in searchme[] and produce 1 list that contains entries by id that are a) in every list, and b) have the same value for score. So searchme[0][index].id = searchme[1][index].id = ... searchme[n][index].id where ALSO  searchme[0][index].score = searchme[1][index].score = ... searchme[n][index].score

Comment: so where // sample ``` searchme[] =[
 [{'id': 1, 'score': 1}, {'id': 2, 'score': 1}, {'id': 3, 'score': 1}],
  [{'id': 1, 'score': 2}, {'id': 2, 'score': 1}, {'id': 4, 'score': 3}],
 [{'id': 1, 'score': 1}, {'id': 2, 'score': 1}, {'id': 3, 'score': 1}], ];```

I'd want to get back results[] = [{'id':2, 'score':1}]; 
to then use to

Comment: @Poi, what if the objects with id==2 have different scores?

Comment: I assumed an answer and edited to demo the same behavior as in your comment

Comment: if multiple objects with id === 2 have different scores, they don't appear in the output , just as the other ides in there were sequestered out because they don't all match. (Also, Poi is a hawaiian dish, @Pol is my name ;)